# How do I disable the focus ring (or highlight) around a button in SwiftUI on MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

My app includes two buttons, and, wanting to be a good platform citizen, I'd like the user to be able to navigate them using the keyboard when they have `System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard navigation` on.

However, this creates a really hideous highlight around my buttons that I can't seem to get rid of.

Ideally, I'd want to customize my button style when the button has focus (e.g. changing the background, or making the text bold).

See the below image, where the left button has focus and has an ugly orange ring around it, partially obscuring the drop shadow:

[image: App screenshot, showing the highlight around the left button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `FocusState` to track which button is currently selected by keyboard navigation. Using this, you can write a custom `ButtonStyle` that creates your custom focus effect when the button is focused. You can turn off the default focus effect (the blue outline) by using `.focusEffectDisabled()`.

To pass the focus state to the `ButtonStyle` is a bit difficult. The `isFocused` environment value somehow doesn't work here. You can modify each button individually with a `.buttonStyle` modifier with different parameters like in Benzy Neez's answer, but I would prefer to use a custom environment value.

For example, here is a button style that enlarges the button when it is focused.

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.customFocus) var focus
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(focus ? 1.5 : 1)
    }
}

struct CustomFocusKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var customFocus: Bool {
        get { self[CustomFocusKey.self] }
        set { self[CustomFocusKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

You can use a `ViewModifier` to pass the focus state:

```
struct CustomFocusModifier: ViewModifier {
    @FocusState var focus: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .focused($focus)
            .environment(\.customFocus, focus)
    }
}

extension View {
    func customFocus() -> some View {
        modifier(CustomFocusModifier())
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
HStack {
    Button("Foo") { ... }
        .customFocus()
    Button("Bar") { ... }
        .customFocus()
}
.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
.focusEffectDisabled()
```

Answer (score 1):

The color of the focus highlight is derived from your *accent color*. So if you wanted to change it to something more neutral, you could change the accent color.

For more control of styling, you can apply your own `ButtonStyle`:

- If you want to style the button differently when it has focus, you can detect when this is the case using a `FocusState` variable and then pass a flag to the style.
- The focus border can be disabled by applying `.focusEffectDisabled()`.

Using a `FocusState` variable also allows you to set focus on a particular button programmatically, if you should want to. For example, this can be useful for setting focus on the OK button of a dialog.

```swift
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let isFocused: Bool
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth: 100)
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .fontWeight(isFocused ? .bold : .regular)
            .border(.black)
            .background(
                Group {
                    isFocused ? Color.yellow : Color.white
                }
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, x: 2, y: 2)
            )
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: isFocused)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    enum ButtonPurpose {
        case start
        case reset
    }

    @FocusState private var isFocused: ButtonPurpose?

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button("Start") {}
                .focused($isFocused, equals: .start)
                .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle(isFocused: isFocused == .start))
                .focusEffectDisabled()
            Button("Reset") {}
                .focused($isFocused, equals: .reset)
                .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle(isFocused: isFocused == .reset))
        }
    }
}
```

The focus effect has only been disabled on the first button, so it can still be seen on the second (with default accent color of blue):

[image: Animation]